# Minimizing NExpectation for a custom distribution

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, mathematical-optimization

As discussed and advised in [Meta: Migrate a question...](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/migrate-a-question-from-stackoverflow-to-mathematica-stackexchange-com?cb=1), I've copied a 2012 posted question from StackOverflow (posted before this site began running), which has gotten a lot of attention (but after 3 years it just got an answer).  Too old to migrate, but the question still seems more suited for this site.  @azt who answered in August has offered to to add his answer here.

---

This relates to an earlier question from 2012 on StackOverflow:

[Calculating expectation for a custom distribution in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296455/calculating-expectation-for-a-custom-distribution-in-mathematica)

I have a custom mixed distribution defined using a second custom distribution following along the lines discussed by `@Sasha` in a number of answers over the past year.

Code defining the distributions follows:

```
nDist /: CharacteristicFunction[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], 
   t_] := (a b E^(I m t - (s^2 t^2)/2))/((I a + t) (-I b + t));
nDist /: PDF[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], x_] := (1/(2*(a + b)))*a* 
   b*(E^(a*(m + (a*s^2)/2 - x))* Erfc[(m + a*s^2 - x)/(Sqrt[2]*s)] + 
     E^(b*(-m + (b*s^2)/2 + x))* 
      Erfc[(-m + b*s^2 + x)/(Sqrt[2]*s)]); 
nDist /: CDF[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], 
   x_] := ((1/(2*(a + b)))*((a + b)*E^(a*x)* 
        Erfc[(m - x)/(Sqrt[2]*s)] - 
       b*E^(a*m + (a^2*s^2)/2)*Erfc[(m + a*s^2 - x)/(Sqrt[2]*s)] + 
       a*E^((-b)*m + (b^2*s^2)/2 + a*x + b*x)*
        Erfc[(-m + b*s^2 + x)/(Sqrt[2]*s)]))/ E^(a*x);         

nDist /: Quantile[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], p_] :=  
 Module[{x}, 
   x /. FindRoot[CDF[nDist[a, b, m, s], x] == #, {x, m}] & /@ p] /; 
  VectorQ[p, 0 < # < 1 &]
nDist /: Quantile[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], p_] := 
 Module[{x}, x /. FindRoot[CDF[nDist[a, b, m, s], x] == p, {x, m}]] /;
   0 < p < 1
nDist /: Quantile[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], p_] := -Infinity /; p == 0
nDist /: Quantile[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], p_] := Infinity /; p == 1
nDist /: Mean[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := 1/a - 1/b + m;
nDist /: Variance[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := 1/a^2 + 1/b^2 + s^2;
nDist /: StandardDeviation[ nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := 
  Sqrt[ 1/a^2 + 1/b^2 + s^2];
nDist /: DistributionDomain[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := 
 Interval[{0, Infinity}]
nDist /: DistributionParameterQ[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := ! 
  TrueQ[Not[Element[{a, b, s, m}, Reals] && a > 0 && b > 0 && s > 0]]
nDist /: DistributionParameterAssumptions[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := 
 Element[{a, b, s, m}, Reals] && a > 0 && b > 0 && s > 0
nDist /: Random`DistributionVector[nDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], n_, prec_] :=

    RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[a], n, 
    WorkingPrecision -> prec] - 
   RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[b], n, 
    WorkingPrecision -> prec] + 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[m, s], n, 
    WorkingPrecision -> prec];

(* Fitting: This uses Mean, central moments 2 and 3 and 4th cumulant \
but it often does not provide a solution *)

nDistParam[data_] := Module[{mn, vv, m3, k4, al, be, m, si},
      mn = Mean[data];
      vv = CentralMoment[data, 2];
      m3 = CentralMoment[data, 3];
      k4 = Cumulant[data, 4];
      al = 
    ConditionalExpression[
     Root[864 - 864 m3 #1^3 - 216 k4 #1^4 + 648 m3^2 #1^6 + 
        36 k4^2 #1^8 - 216 m3^3 #1^9 + (-2 k4^3 + 27 m3^4) #1^12 &, 
      2], k4 > Root[-27 m3^4 + 4 #1^3 &, 1]];
      be = ConditionalExpression[

     Root[2 Root[
           864 - 864 m3 #1^3 - 216 k4 #1^4 + 648 m3^2 #1^6 + 
             36 k4^2 #1^8 - 
             216 m3^3 #1^9 + (-2 k4^3 + 27 m3^4) #1^12 &, 
           2]^3 + (-2 + 
           m3 Root[
              864 - 864 m3 #1^3 - 216 k4 #1^4 + 648 m3^2 #1^6 + 
                36 k4^2 #1^8 - 
                216 m3^3 #1^9 + (-2 k4^3 + 27 m3^4) #1^12 &, 
              2]^3) #1^3 &, 1], k4 > Root[-27 m3^4 + 4 #1^3 &, 1]];
      m = mn - 1/al + 1/be;
      si = 
    Sqrt[Abs[-al^-2 - be^-2 + vv ]];(*Ensure positive*)
      {al, 
    be, m, si}];

nDistLL = 
  Compile[{a, b, m, s, {x, _Real, 1}}, 
   Total[Log[
     1/(2 (a + 
           b)) a b (E^(a (m + (a s^2)/2 - x)) Erfc[(m + a s^2 - 
             x)/(Sqrt[2] s)] + 
        E^(b (-m + (b s^2)/2 + x)) Erfc[(-m + b s^2 + 
             x)/(Sqrt[2] s)])]](*, CompilationTarget->"C", 
   RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True*)];

nlloglike[data_, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 
  nDistLL[a, b, m, s, data];

nFit[data_] := Module[{a, b, m, s, a0, b0, m0, s0, res},

      (* So far have not found a good way to quickly estimate a and \
b.  Starting assumption is that they both = 2,then m0 ~= 
   Mean and s0 ~= 
   StandardDeviation it seems to work better if a and b are not the \
same at start. *)

   {a0, b0, m0, s0} = nDistParam[data];(*may give Undefined values*)

     If[! (VectorQ[{a0, b0, m0, s0}, NumericQ] && 
       VectorQ[{a0, b0, s0}, # > 0 &]),
            m0 = Mean[data];
            s0 = StandardDeviation[data];
            a0 = 1;
            b0 = 2;];
   res = {a, b, m, s} /. 
     FindMaximum[
       nlloglike[data, Abs[a], Abs[b], m,  
        Abs[s]], {{a, a0}, {b, b0}, {m, m0}, {s, s0}},
               Method -> "PrincipalAxis"][[2]];
      {Abs[res[[1]]], Abs[res[[2]]], res[[3]], Abs[res[[4]]]}];

nFit[data_, {a0_, b0_, m0_, s0_}] := Module[{a, b, m, s, res},
      res = {a, b, m, s} /. 
     FindMaximum[
       nlloglike[data, Abs[a], Abs[b], m, 
        Abs[s]], {{a, a0}, {b, b0}, {m, m0}, {s, s0}},
               Method -> "PrincipalAxis"][[2]];
      {Abs[res[[1]]], Abs[res[[2]]], res[[3]], Abs[res[[4]]]}];

dDist /: PDF[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], x_] := 
  PDF[nDist[a, b, m, s], Log[x]]/x;
dDist /: CDF[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], x_] := 
  CDF[nDist[a, b, m, s], Log[x]];
dDist /: EstimatedDistribution[data_, dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := 
  dDist[Sequence @@ nFit[Log[data]]];
dDist /: EstimatedDistribution[data_, 
   dDist[a_, b_, m_, 
    s_], {{a_, a0_}, {b_, b0_}, {m_, m0_}, {s_, s0_}}] := 
  dDist[Sequence @@ nFit[Log[data], {a0, b0, m0, s0}]];
dDist /: Quantile[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], p_] := 
 Module[{x}, x /. FindRoot[CDF[dDist[a, b, m, s], x] == p, {x, s}]] /;
   0 < p < 1
dDist /: Quantile[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], p_] :=  
 Module[{x}, 
   x /. FindRoot[ CDF[dDist[a, b, m, s], x] == #, {x, s}] & /@ p] /; 
  VectorQ[p, 0 < # < 1 &]
dDist /: Quantile[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], p_] := -Infinity /; p == 0
dDist /: Quantile[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], p_] := Infinity /; p == 1
dDist /: DistributionDomain[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := 
 Interval[{0, Infinity}]
dDist /: DistributionParameterQ[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := ! 
  TrueQ[Not[Element[{a, b, s, m}, Reals] && a > 0 && b > 0 && s > 0]]
dDist /: DistributionParameterAssumptions[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_]] := 
 Element[{a, b, s, m}, Reals] && a > 0 && b > 0 && s > 0
dDist /: Random`DistributionVector[dDist[a_, b_, m_, s_], n_, prec_] :=
   Exp[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[a], n, 
     WorkingPrecision -> prec] - 
       RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[b], n, 
     WorkingPrecision -> prec] + 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[m, s], n, 
     WorkingPrecision -> prec]];
```

This enables me to fit distribution parameters and generate **PDF's** and **CDF's**.  An example of the plots:

```
Plot[PDF[dDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40], x], {x, 0, .3}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
Plot[CDF[dDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40], x], {x, 0, .3}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now I've defined a `function` to calculate mean residual life (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104494/mean-residual-life-clarification-needed) for an explanation).

```
MeanResidualLife[start_, dist_] := 
 NExpectation[X \[Conditioned] X > start, X \[Distributed] dist] - 
  start
MeanResidualLife[start_, limit_, dist_] := 
 NExpectation[X \[Conditioned] start <= X <= limit, 
   X \[Distributed] dist] - start
```

The first of these that doesn't set a limit as in the second takes a long time to calculate, but they both work.

Now I need to find the minimum of the `MeanResidualLife` function for the same distribution (or some variation of it) or minimize it.

I've tried a number of variations on this:

```
FindMinimum[MeanResidualLife[x, dDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40]], x]
FindMinimum[MeanResidualLife[x, 1, dDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40]], x]

NMinimize[{MeanResidualLife[x, dDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40]], 
  0 <= x <= 1}, x]
NMinimize[{MeanResidualLife[x, 1, dDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40]], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

These either seem to run forever or run into:

> Power::infy : Infinite expression 1/ 0. encountered. >>

The `MeanResidualLife` function applied to a simpler but similarly shaped distribution shows that it has a single minimum:

```
Plot[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65], x], {x, 0, 30}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
Plot[MeanResidualLife[x, LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65]], {x, 0, 
  30},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {4.5, 8}}]
```

[image]

Also both:

```
FindMinimum[MeanResidualLife[x, LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65]], x]
FindMinimum[MeanResidualLife[x, 30, LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65]], x]
```

give me answers (if with a bunch of messages first) when used with the `LogNormalDistribution`.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work for the custom distribution described above?

Do I need to add constraints or options?

Do I need to define something else in the definitions of the custom distributions?

Maybe the `FindMinimum` or `NMinimize` just need to run longer (I've run them nearly an hour to no avail).  If so do I just need some way to speed up finding the minimum of the function?  Any suggestions on how?

Does `Mathematica` have another way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

**Added 9 Feb 5:50PM EST:**

Anyone can download **Oleksandr Pavlyk's** presentation about creating distributions in Mathematica from the Wolfram Technology Conference 2011 workshop 'Create Your Own Distribution' [here](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/mathematics-and-statistics.html).  The downloads include the notebook, `'ExampleOfParametricDistribution.nb'` that seems to lays out all the pieces required to create a distribution that one can use like the distributions that come with Mathematica.

It may supply some of the answer.

Comment: @azt -- You're up.  Thanks again.

Comment: Jagra, azt did not get a ping from your comment above (see [this SE meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for how pings work); you will want to ping them from the *Meta* discussion in which they participated.

Comment: @MarcoB - Thanks for the head's up.

Comment: @Jagra, here it is. Have you had time to go through my answer? Maybe we should put a comment on SO that the copy is now here...

Comment: @azt -- Not certain of the protocol for informing SO, perhaps one of our moderators can advise.  And now I need to dig into your answer...

Comment: @Jagra, adding a link to this from the SO version should suffice.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I see, the problem is (as you already wrote), that `MeanResidualLife` takes a long time to compute, even for a single evaluation. Now, the `FindMinimum` or similar functions try to find a minimum to the function. Finding a minimum requires either to set the first derivative of the function zero and solve for a solution. Since your function is quite complicated (and probably not differentiable), the second possibility is to do a numerical minimization, which requires many evaluations of your function. Ergo, it is very very slow.

I'd suggest to try it without Mathematica magic.

First let's see what the `MeanResidualLife` is, as you defined it. `NExpectation` or `Expectation` compute the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). 
For the expected value, we only need the `PDF` of your distribution. Let's extract it from your definition above into simple functions:

```
pdf[a_, b_, m_, s_, x_] := (1/(2*(a + b)))*a*b*
    (E^(a*(m + (a*s^2)/2 - x))*Erfc[(m + a*s^2 - x)/(Sqrt[2]*s)] + 
    E^(b*(-m + (b*s^2)/2 + x))*Erfc[(-m + b*s^2 + x)/(Sqrt[2]*s)])
pdf2[a_, b_, m_, s_, x_] := pdf[a, b, m, s, Log[x]]/x;
```

If we plot pdf2 it looks exactly as your Plot

```
Plot[pdf2[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40, x], {x, 0, .3}]
```

[image: Plot of PDF]

Now to the expected value. If I understand it correctly we have to integrate `x * pdf[x]` from `-inf` to `+inf` for a normal expected value.

`x * pdf[x]` looks like

```
Plot[pdf2[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40, x]*x, {x, 0, .3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot of x * PDF]

and the expected value is

```
NIntegrate[pdf2[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40, x]*x, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
Out= 0.0596504
```

But since you want the expected value between a `start` and `+inf` we need to integrate in this range, and since the PDF then no longer integrates to 1 in this smaller interval, I guess we have to normalize the result be dividing by the integral of the PDF in this range. So my guess for the left-bound expected value is

```
expVal[start_] := 
    NIntegrate[pdf2[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40, x]*x, {x, start, \[Infinity]}]/
    NIntegrate[pdf2[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40, x], {x, start, \[Infinity]}]
```

And for the `MeanResidualLife` you subtract `start` from it, giving

```
MRL[start_] := expVal[start] - start
```

Which plots as

```
Plot[MRL[start], {start, 0, 0.3}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image: Plot of Mean Residual Life]

Looks plausible, but I'm no expert. So finally we want to minimize it, i.e. find the `start` for which this function is a local minimum. The minimum seems to be around 0.05, but let's find a more exact value starting from that guess

```
FindMinimum[MRL[start], {start, 0.05}]
```

and after some errors (your function is not defined below 0, so I guess the minimizer pokes a little in that forbidden region) we get

{0.0418137, {start -> 0.0584312}}

So the optimum should be at `start = 0.0584312` with a mean residual life of `0.0418137`.

I don't know if this is correct, but it seems plausible.